# How to turn INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE into a multiple query IF YOU're updating the key

Tags: mysql

How do I turn these two queries into a single one:

```
INSERT INTO planet_market (resource_id, price,amount) VALUES 
(6, 999, 100)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
amount = amount + 100

INSERT INTO planet_market (resource_id, price,amount) VALUES 
(6, 777, 60)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
amount = amount + 60
```

into a multiple query

```
INSERT INTO planet_market (resource_id, amount, type, price,owner_type,planet_id, factory_id)  
VALUES (6, 999, 100),
(6, 777, 60)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
amount = amount + VALUES(amount)
```

EDIT!!!: I got it working with the amount = amount +VALUES(amount)

P.S.: I didn't know how to add it up and there was actually something else wrong with my query afterall(forgot to cut a comma off when assembling the query together)

Comment: Could you possibly elaborate your question and provide a small schema sample as well as expected results?

Comment: @Martin I simplified and expanded the question, should be more understandable now. Don't think you need a schema to understand this now.

Comment: uhm I think I just got it to work with  amount = amount + VALUES(amount) lol

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using the `SUM()` function.

```
amount = SUM(amount + VALUES(amount))
```

Comment: Do you know if that's better in anyway than just simply: amount = amount + VALUES(amount) ?